# select dynamic options do not set values angular 14

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular14

I have a configuration array list of my list of roles and groups with their respective values ​​correctly.

but the iterated values ​​are correct and the ones that are displayed in the select are the first of my "configuration" array

```
   <div class="container">

           <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of configuracion; let i = index">
             <div class="col-lg-5" >
               <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label">grupo {{item.id_group}}</label>
               <select class="form-select" name="uno" [(ngModel)]="item.id_group">
                 <option *ngFor="let objGrupo of lstGrupos" [value]="objGrupo.id">{{objGrupo.name}}</option>
               </select>
             </div>
           <div class="col-lg-5" >
             <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label">Rol {{item.id_role}} </label>
             <select class="form-select" name="dos" [(ngModel)]="item.id_role">
               <option *ngFor="let objeto of lstRoles" [value]="objeto.id">{{objeto.name}}</option>
             </select>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">
             <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger"  type="button" >
               <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
               eliminar
             </button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

typescript:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configuracion.push(
      {id:0, id_group: Number(101), id_perfil:0, id_role: Number(204)},
      {id:0, id_group: Number( 104), id_perfil:0, id_role: Number( 305)}
    )
  }
```

[even next to role and group the ids are set correctly but on select it doesn't show what is the value string of the id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7SQm.png)

I try with select to match when the id of my "configuration" array is equal to the id of my list of groups and the same with my list of roles

```
 <div class="col-lg-5" >
                <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label">grupo {{item.id_group}}</label>
                <select class="form-select" name="uno" [(ngModel)]="item.id_group">
                  <option *ngFor="let objGrupo of lstGrupos" [value]="objGrupo.id" [selected]="item.id_group==objGrupo.id">{{objGrupo.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
```